# Localization not getting right sound

Tags: c#, audio, localization, resx

I have three resx files for three languages, Resources.resx, Resources.en-gb.resx and Resources.de-de.resx . When i change the locale all the strings do translate, but the sound files do not. I have the right sound files in the right resx files.

**Changing the locale:**

```
SelectedLanguage = locale;
Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo(locale);
```

*With locale being a string like "en-gb".*

**Getting the audio file:**

```
SoundPlayer _player = new SoundPlayer(Resources.Alarm);
```

When in change the language i want to get the sound file with the right language instead of the one from the default Resources.resx file.

Comment: either you have any static path location in the code or double check the sound files location whether the proper sound files are proper place or not

Comment: @A.GopalReddy The resx files have the right sound file in the code, and in the main code I dont use a path, just resources.Alarm;.

Comment: what is the type of  `resources.Alarm`? String or Stream?

Comment: @kennyzx a stream `<value>..\Resource\alarm_english.wav;System.IO.MemoryStream,... </value>`

Comment: I think the localization framework does not ‘trigger’ the creation of the SoundPlayer instance again when you change the locale, so it still plays the default wav file. For labels, images, which are displayed to the user, they are refreshed. So you may need to listen to the event of locale changed, and recreate the SoundPlayer in the event handler.

Comment: @kennyzx I do restart the app after the locale changes, to be sure. That means the SoundPlayer sould be created with the right locale set.